# Inputing a list of words from the file and then choosing a random word?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, random, input

So I'm working on a Hangman game and since the words is in a text file, I want to put the words into an array and pick a random work from the array and use it as my secret word. Any help will be great. thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_NUMS = 200;   // Constant for the maximum number of words.
const int MAX_GUESSES = 8;
const string LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


//function prototypes
char   inputLetter();
int    findChar(char letter, string word);
string getGuessedWord(string secretWord, string lettersGuessed);

//main function
int main()
{
    string word;                    // holds one word from input file
    string secretWord;              // holds secret word to be guessed
    string words[MAX_NUMS];         // holds list of words from input file
    int randomValue;                // holds index of secret word
    int count = 0;                  // holds number of words in the file

    // Declare an ifstream object named myFile and open an input file
    string line;

    ifstream myfile ("p4words.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (! myfile.eof() )
        {
            getline (myfile,line);

            cout << line << endl;
        }
         myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    // Input words from a file into words array
    {
        ifstream myfile("p4words.txt");

        if(myfile.is_open())
        {
            string words[MAX_NUMS];

            for(int count = 0; count < MAX_NUMS; count++)
            { 
                myfile >> words[count];
            }
        }

    }


    cout << count << " words loaded." << endl;

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    // Select a secret word
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `#include <random>` if you have C++11. You can do something like

```
#include <random> 
...

std::random_device rd; // source of randomness
std::mt19937 rng(rd()); // seed random number engine
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> uid(0,words.size() - 1);
std::size_t sample = uid(rng); 

std::cout << words[sample] << std::endl; // uniform randomly chosen word
```

See full example on http://ideone.com/uD04b9

In case you do not have a C++11 compliant compiler, you have to use the old `srand()/rand()` functions to simulate a uniform distribution, something like:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
sample = static_cast<std::size_t>(rand() % words.size()); // uniform distribution
std::cout << words[sample] << std::endl; // uniform randomly chosen word
```